# Get name of component (combobox) and output in ALERT

Tags: extjs, combobox, alert

Given the following configuration to an Ext JS combo box:

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    width: 350,
    store: 'price.Book', 
     name: 'books'
}
```

I want to listen for the change event on the combobox and alert it's name.

```
change: function(combo) {
    var dateObj777= Ext.ClassManager.getName('books');
    alert(dateObj777.name);
}
```

"undefined" is alerted when i'm expecting the name.

Comment: try alerting `combo.name`

Comment: if i am want get name another combo. (i am have 2 combo and when change 1 combo ALERT output name 2 combo)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to use the `itemId` property in conjunction with `Ext.ComponentQuery.query()`, something like

```
 {
    xtype: 'combobox',
    width: 350,
    store: 'price.Book', 
    name: 'books',
    itemId: 'booksCombo'
}

...

change: function(thisCombo) {
    var otherCombo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#booksCombo')[0];
    alert(otherCombo.name);
}
```